# sign the axes in the place I need, make axis marks italic and reduce size

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can’t move the axis label to the place I want, nor can I italicize the axis marks and reduce the size of the digits

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[12pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
            mark=none,
            domain=0:400,samples=50,smooth}, 
        xlabel = {$ h $},
        ylabel = {$ W (h) $},
        axis lines = middle,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        grid = both,
        major grid style = {lightgray},
        minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
        enlargelimits=upper] 
        \addplot[black, line width = 1pt] {sin(x)};
        \end{axis}          
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image]

#### Notes:

- I defined `Axis Labels At Tip` to move the labels to the tips
- Removed the `axis x line=bottom`

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[12pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Axis Labels At Tip/.style={
        xlabel style={
            at={(current axis.right of origin)}, 
            anchor=west,
        },
        ylabel style={
            at={(current axis.above origin)}, 
            yshift=1.5ex, anchor=center
        }
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
            mark=none,
            domain=0:400,samples=50,smooth,
            }, 
        xlabel = {$ h $},
        ylabel = {$ W (h) $},
        axis lines = middle,
        %axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        grid = both,
        major grid style = {lightgray},
        minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
        enlargelimits=upper,
        Axis Labels At Tip,
        ] 
        \addplot[black, line width = 1pt] {sin(x)};
\end{axis}          
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, but if it's not difficult for you, tell me how to make italics and reduce the font size, and it seems like you can move the signature from the central direction to any side by a certain distance?

Comment: You cah change the font via `xticklabel style={font=\small}` and similarily for the `yticklabel`.